# PostgreSQL Monitor Logical replication Failure and Lag

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, postgresql-11, amazon-aurora, logical-replication

I have logical replication running among multiple PostgreSQL environments. I need to setup some alerting mechanism where I get an alert if one of my logical replication failed for whatever reason.
How can I achieve that?
I am aware of these Views, on which column can I use where class to catch the failure?

pg_stat_replication
Pg_publication_tables
Pg_replication_slots
pg_stat_subscription
pg_subscription_rel

Let me know,
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT max(pg_lsn_diff(
          pg_current_wal_lsn(),
          replay_lsn
       ))
FROM pg_stat_replication;
```

That will tell you how many bytes the most delayed standby server is behind.

Comment: Should this also work for logical replication? On my Postgres 11 instance all columns except for pid, usesysid, usename, application_name ar null even though I have an active logical replication

Comment: I guess it is only for streaming replication.